# Download jMonkeyEngine using SBT

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt, jmonkeyengine

I am trying to use [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) 3 with Scala (using IntelliJ as an IDE, in a SBT driven Scala project). As [Maven distribution](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3_maven_repo) was added few months ago, I try to pull the JME from this maven repository. This is what I have added into my build.sbt file:

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jmonkeyengine3" % "3.0.0.20140325-SNAPSHOT"
```

The only jar downloaded `jmonkeyengine3-3.0.0.20140325-SNAPSHOT.jar` seems to contain the tests only (folder jme3test), not the JME libraries itself. What needs to be added to that they are downloaded as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check their [pom.xml](https://www.assembla.com/code/friendularity/subversion/nodes/771/trunk/maven/org.friendularity.demo.jme3.maven/pom.xml). It seems, that jmonkeyengine3 just contains demo classes. And you need to download additional dependencies. Also, using of Maven dependency is not recommended. They recommend to use SDK installer instead.

Answer (score 4):

As mkrakhin wrote in his answer, it is necessary to add all dependencies. The SBT code for this is as follows:

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

val jmeVersion = "3.0.0.20140325-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jmonkeyengine3" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jME3-desktop" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jME3-core" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jME3-lwjgl" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "lwjgl" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jME3-lwjgl-natives" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jME3-jbullet" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jbullet" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jME3-blender" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jME3-desktop" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jME3-effects" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jME3-networking" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jME3-plugins" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jME3-terrain" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jME3-jogg" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "j-ogg-oggd" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "j-ogg-vorbisd" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jinput" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "eventbus" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "stack-alloc" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "vecmath" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "xmlpull-xpp3" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "jME3-niftygui" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "nifty" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "nifty-default-controls" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "nifty-examples" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.jme3" % "nifty-style-black" % jmeVersion

libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "3.8.1"
```

Comment: Note: it is getting more support, see http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php/jme3:maven