# Tell SBT not to check a SNAPSHOT version for changes

Tags: scala, sbt

This is similar to [Re-download a SNAPSHOT version of a dependency using SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224907/re-download-a-snapshot-version-of-a-dependency-using-sbt), but I would like to achieve the opposite - I would like to tell SBT it does not have to check SNAPSHOT version for changes. How can I do that?

Motivation is when using [jME3 via SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24677826/16673), jME3 does not follow usual conventions and each SNAPSHOT version already gets the version stamp in its name. As there are many components of jME3, checking for each of them for changes seems to slow down the build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sbt internally marks all dependencies, which are `-SNAPSHOT` as changing. You can check the [`changing()` documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/api/#sbt.ModuleID).

I don't think you can change this easily as this seem to be coded in the sources. I think you could set `offline` to `true`, which should hold the update process.

You can do it in the `build.sbt` or just from console via `set offline := true`.

Answer (score 4):

I think the closest is the `offline` setting:

- Adding the setting `offline := true` to your build.sbt should disable dependency resolution for snapshots.
- To set this globally on your machine, put it in `~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt`

From [the documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Dependency-Management-Flow.html#Caching+and+Configuration):

> When `offline := true`, remote SNAPSHOTs will not be updated by a resolution, even an explicitly requested update. This should effectively support working without a connection to remote repositories. Reproducible examples demonstrating otherwise are appreciated. Obviously, update must have successfully run before going offline.

Answer (score 2):

Just found out about the `skip` setting that:

> For tasks that support it (currently only 'compile' and 'update'), setting skip to true will force the task to not to do its
>   work.  This exact semantics may vary by task.

So use `skip in update := true` or `skip in compile := true` to skip the work.